# Error "expected primary-expression before int"

Tags: c++, function

I'm writing a code that will (hopefully) allow the user to input a number, and which will output the sum of the prime numbers between 2 and that number (inclusive). I'm getting one problem, however, on the penultimate line of the code. I've looked up other solutions to this question, but they don't seem to be caused by the same error as mine. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Q;

int sum_primes(int N) {

    cout << "Enter a number and I will generate the sums of the primes up to (and including) that number: ";
    cin >> Q;

    int i, count, sum = 0;

    for(N = 1; N <= Q; N++) {    
         count = 0;

         for(i = 2; i <= N/2; i++) {
             if (N % i == 0) {
                 count++;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if (count == 0 && N != 1)
             sum = sum + N;

         return N = sum;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "The sum of these primes is: " << sum_primes(int N);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cout << "..." << sum_primes(int N);
```

Replace `int N` with a number. You already defined the function, now you need to give it a parameter.

Or maybe you wanted to give `N`'s value through user input. Then use this instead:

```
int N;

cin >> N;

cout << "The sum of these primes is: " << sum_primes(N);
```

Also, as GigaWatt pointed out, the line on which you did:

```
return N = sum;
```

is unnecessary. Simply returning `sum` will work just as well.

Here's the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool isPrime(int x) {

    if (x == 1) return false;
    if (x == 2) return true;

    bool prime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(x); i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) { prime = false; break; }
    }
    return prime;
}

int sum_primes(unsigned int N) {

    int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) {

        if (isPrime(i)) sum += i;

    }
    return sum == 0 ? 1 : sum;
}

int main() {

    int Q;

    std::cin >> Q;

    std::cout << "Sum of primes " << sum_primes(Q);

}
```

Comment: Also, even though I'm pretty sure it's legal, `return N = sum;` should probably just be `return sum;`.

Comment: I did wish to give N's value through user input - and the way in which you suggest is very simple - but the problem I am faced with runs as follows:
•Write:
•a function int sum_primes(int N) that returns the sum of all the prime numbers (that is: integers that are only divisible by 1 and themselves) between 1 and parameter N.
•a program that asks the user to enter a number Q and prints onto the console the sum of all prime numbers up to Q, using the sum_primes(int N) function.

How would I go about doing that? (The code was probably a lot cleaner before I fiddled with it after 1st error).

Comment: @user1791960 That's the same thing as I did! Make a variable: `int Q` **outside** the function like I did. And make give it a user-generated value (`cin >> Q`). And then write it out `cout << sum_primes(Q)`. It's the same thing as you saw in my answer, only the variable is different :)

Comment: @user1791960 Check the edit I made. See if that works for you. Can you also accept my answer please?

Comment: @David I think I understand what you are saying there. My int Q is outside the function, and is entered as above (in my original question post). Whenever I have cout << sum_primes(Q), though, I get that "The sum of these primes is: 0", regardless of what number I put in. Is there something else wrong with the code?

Comment: Hate to say it, but I'm still getting "The sum of these primes is: 0" with your code.  :/

Comment: @David No, I don't think it's fixed. Now I'm just getting the number, itself, back again. (eg. I enter 7, "the sum of these primes is: 7". If I enter 4, the answer's 4, etc.)
Scratch that ^. Now I'm getting an empty box.  :/

Comment: @David Okay... but 21 would still not be the correct answer. 17 would be. 2+3+5+7 = 17.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out. I'm getting close but I know it has to do with integer division or something. Hold on.

Comment: @user1791960 You should be using `sqrt(x)` instead of `x/2` to check for primes by the way. That was one of many problems I found.

Comment: @David Thanks. Worked it out, I believe. From the second "for-loop" onwards, N should be x, instead. I'll change the x/2 to sqrt(x) now. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact multiple issues with this code. I'll list a few, but this is by no means exhaustive!

- You've got some slightly crazy structuring of your code there. I guess this will become apparent when you fix the simple syntax error. Just as a point of style, I'd pass in `Q` as an argument to `sum_primes` as well as `N`.
- You're outputting "The sum of these primes is" before asking "Enter a number".
- `return N = sum` will exit your outer `for`-loop immediately. This is almost certainly not what you wanted.

I suspect you'll need to hunt down a better instroduction to C++ than you're currently working from. I'm afraid I can't offer you any advice with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument to sum_primes is incorrect.

The function is defined to take an int, but you're not passing it one.