# Expected primary-expression before 'int' when calling a member function inside another member function

Tags: c++, function, class

I have just started learning c++ and thought I'd try to gauge my understanding by doing a small project
I am creating a program that simulates a vending machine, using a class and member functions. I only get the following 2 errors:
expected primary expection before 'int'

I tried removing the int, but it gave me an undefined reference to variable error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

class DrinkMachine
{
  private:
    const int COST_OF_DRINK = 150;

  public:
    int RunningTotal;

    DrinkMachine()
    {
      RunningTotal = 0;
    }

    void DepositCoins(int money)
    {

      std::cout << "You can deposit coins of values 25, 50 and 100" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Enter a coin: " << std::endl;

      switch(money)
      {
        case(25):
          RunningTotal += 25;
          break;

        case(50):
            RunningTotal += 50;
            break;

        case(100):
            RunningTotal += 100;
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "You entered the wrong coin" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Coins of values 25, 50, 100 are allowed" << std::endl;
            break;
      }
    }


    bool CheckTotal()
    {
      if(RunningTotal >= COST_OF_DRINK)
        return true;

      else
        return false;
    }

    void MakeDrinkSelection(int DrinkChoice)
    {

      bool IsChoiceValid = false;

      while(!IsChoiceValid)
      {
        switch(DrinkChoice)
        {
          case (1):
            std::cout << "Thank you for choosing Coffee!" << std::endl;
            ReturnChange();
            IsChoiceValid = true;
            break;

          case(2):
            std::cout << "Thank you for choosing Hot Chocolate!" << std::endl;
            IsChoiceValid = true;
            ReturnChange();
            break;

          case(3):
            std::cout << "Thank you for choosing Green Tea!" << std::endl;
            IsChoiceValid = true;
            ReturnChange();
            break;

          default:
            std::cout << "Invalid selection. Please re-enter your choice" << std::endl;
            bool NewDrinkChoice;
            DrinkChoice = NewDrinkChoice;
            IsChoiceValid = false;
            break;
        }
      }
    }


    void DisplayDrinks()
    {
      std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "1. Coffee" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "2. Hot Chocolate" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "3. Green Tea" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Please make a choice: " << std::endl;
      MakeDrinkSelection(int DrinkChoice);  //gives an error

    }

    void ReturnChange()
    {
      if(RunningTotal > COST_OF_DRINK)
      {
        std::cout << "Your change is: " << (RunningTotal - COST_OF_DRINK) << std::endl;
      }
    }
};


int main()
{


  //DrinkMachine drinkmachine = new DrinkMachine();
  DrinkMachine mydrink;

  while(!mydrink.CheckTotal())
  {
    mydrink.DepositCoins(int money); //gives an error
  }

  mydrink.DisplayDrinks();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Get rid of `int money` in the call in `main` and in the function defection.  Just have `int money;` in the function body.

Comment: @NathanOliver, That error was made in two places, which shows there is a lesson to be taught about how to call a function with arguments. If this is to be closed I'm sure there's a duplicate out there that could at least forward Advait to an answer.

Comment: @Romen SO is not a replacement for a good reference book.  We do expect some basic knowledge already being known and how to call a function is, at least IMHO, a very basic concept.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried your solution and the program compiled but it created an infinite loop. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "expected primary-expression before int"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182467/error-expected-primary-expression-before-int)

Comment: If that changes dives you an infinite loop then It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the reply. I'm guessing Visual Studio has a debugger? I'll download it give the debugger a shot. Sorry to keep asking the same thing, but is there no other way the code posted above work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many faults in the code. I didn't saw them your program completely before.
I assumed that you might have done it right. Alright then.

first, you should ask what coin is acceptable by the machine at the start of the program which you haven't.

Second, before calling a function by value, you should take input from the user and then pass it to the function, which again you haven't.

Here, I have corrected your code somewhat.

```
    #include <iostream>

    class DrinkMachine
    {
     private:
        const int COST_OF_DRINK = 150;

      public:
        int RunningTotal;

DrinkMachine()
{
  RunningTotal = 0;
}

void DepositCoins(int money)
{



  switch(money)
  {
    case(25):
      RunningTotal += 25;
      break;

    case(50):
        RunningTotal += 50;
        break;

    case(100):
        RunningTotal += 100;
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "You entered the wrong coin" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Coins of values 25, 50, 100 are allowed" << std::endl;
        break;
  }
}


bool CheckTotal()
{
  std::cout << "You can deposit coins of values 25, 50 and 100" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Enter a coin: " << std::endl;
  if(RunningTotal >= COST_OF_DRINK)
    return true;

  else
    return false;
}

void MakeDrinkSelection(int DrinkChoice)
{

  bool IsChoiceValid = false;

  while(!IsChoiceValid)
  {
    switch(DrinkChoice)
    {
      case (1):
        std::cout << "Thank you for choosing Coffee!" << std::endl;
        ReturnChange();
        IsChoiceValid = true;
        break;

      case(2):
        std::cout << "Thank you for choosing Hot Chocolate!" << std::endl;
        IsChoiceValid = true;
        ReturnChange();
        break;

      case(3):
        std::cout << "Thank you for choosing Green Tea!" << std::endl;
        IsChoiceValid = true;
        ReturnChange();
        break;

      default:
        std::cout << "Invalid selection. Please re-enter your choice" << std::endl;
        bool NewDrinkChoice;
        DrinkChoice = NewDrinkChoice;
        IsChoiceValid = false;
        break;
    }
  }
}


void DisplayDrinks()
{
  int DrinkChoice;                //here declared
  std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "1. Coffee" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "2. Hot Chocolate" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "3. Green Tea" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Please make a choice: " << std::endl;
  std::cin>>DrinkChoice;              //input by user
  MakeDrinkSelection(DrinkChoice);  //used to give an error

}

void ReturnChange()
{
  if(RunningTotal > COST_OF_DRINK)
  {
    std::cout << "Your change is: " << (RunningTotal - COST_OF_DRINK) << std::endl;
  }
}
};


    int main()
    {


  //DrinkMachine drinkmachine = new DrinkMachine();
  DrinkMachine mydrink;
  int money;              //here declared

  while(!mydrink.CheckTotal())
  {
  std::cin>>money;          //input by user

    mydrink.DepositCoins(money); //no error
  }

       mydrink.DisplayDrinks();

       return 0;
    }
```

I have cleared the basic error you asked about. But you should correct the errors in logic by yourself.

Hope you will.

Comment: Thank you correcting my code! I will try to solve the logic errors

Comment: Welcome, if(stuck.==true){then ask;}